# Cannot find jupyter notebook after installing anaconda

Tags: python-3.x

I've installed python 3 and I've set path variables. The program runs on anaconda prompt but I can't find jupyter notebook. 
The command "jupyter notebook" isn't running as well.
After searching for answers I checked for jupyter.exe and anaconda-navigator.exe that are present on my system which means I have successfully installed anaconda

But on cmd it shows:
Error executing Jupyter command 'notebook': [Errno 'jupyter-notebook' not found] 2